# windows 8.1 installation : Which partition should I backup/restore

Tags: windows-8.1

I have 2 identical PCs. Both HDDs have GPT structure (but have different partition schemes).

Except the windows 8.1 default partitions ( that are created during windows 8.1 installation , and exists in both pc's hdd ) the partitions are as follows:

- the HDD on first PC has another NTFS partition,
- the HDD on the second PC has 3 other NTFS partitions.

Note that I just want to backup windows from PC1 and to restore on PC2 (I don't want to backup the entire HDD from pc1 to pc2).

I want  to backup/restore the Windows installation from PC1 to PC2 (Windows 8.1).
In addition to the Windows partition, what other partitions should I backup or restore from PC1 to PC2?

Should I backup/restore the EFI partition or any other?

Comment: Corrected spelling and cleaned up your post. Could you list which partitions you have?

Comment: @tiku - Unless you provide the partition information for both HDDs we can't tell you what partitions you need to do.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Except the windows 8.1 default partitions ( that are created during windows 8.1 installation , and exists in both pc's hdd ) , the HDD on first PC has another NTFS partition , the HDD on the second PC has 3 other NTFS partitions. note that I just want to backup windows from PC1 and to restore on PC2 ( I don't want t o backup entire HDD from pc1 to pc2).